# Java EE Primefaces em nuvem

Tags: java, primefaces, cloud

Gostaria de saber se o Java com Primefaces e seus beans gerenciados trabalham bem em nuvem, digo, a minha dúvida é se essa arquitetura suporta trabalhar em nuvem para construção de um sistema web com desempenho aceitável visto que muitas vezes uma tela feita no JSF usando Primefaces chama várias vezes um método Java durante a requisição de uma página (coisa que não entendo muito bem também), outra coisa: dado que sistemas em nuvem devem possuir a propriedade de serem absolutamente stateless, creio que seria necessário neste caso o uso do escopo @RequestScoped correto? porém algo que me deixa inquieto é se o primefaces em si usando os beans gerenciados não fazem uso de nenhum processo 'por debaixo dos panos' que venha a manter um controle de estado no lado servidor o que invalidaria totalmente a ideia de ser livre de sessão, alguém com bom conhecimento neste tipo de arquitetura poderia me ajudar? Agradeço desde já a quem puder ajudar, sei que posso estar sendo meio confuso na formulação das perguntas mas foi a melhor forma que encontrei para me expressar, sintam-se a vontade para replicar caso eu precisem que eu seja mais específico.

Obrigado!!